# Determine a positive / negative word ratio in a tweet set

Tags: python

I have a set of tweets in which I would like to determine a ratio of negative- and positive words ratio.I have the following simplified dictionary's:

```
negative_words = ['bad', 'terrible']
positive_words = ['outstanding', 'good']
```

I wrote the following code to analyze them:

```
tweets = ["this is terrible", "this is very good"]

for tweet in tweets:
 count_positive = 0
 count_negative = 0

 if(tweet in positive_words):
  count_positive = count_positive + 1
 if(tweet in negative_words):
  count_negative = count_negative + 1

 ratio_positive = count_positive / len(tweet)
 ratio_negative = count_negative / len(tweet)
 ratio_negative = float(ratio_negative)
 ratio_positive = float(ratio_positive)

 print(ratio_positive)
 print(ratio_negative)
```

The output of this code should be a ratio of positive vs negative words. However I only get 0.0... while I expect 0.33 etc...

Any thoughts on what goes wrong here?

Comment: python 2 division?

Comment: Instead of casting the output to float, cast any of the operands to float.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you really want to do is to check if each word in the tweet is positive or negative, while currently you are checking if the **whole** tweet is in the positive/negative word set. Thus you never find it and both numbers stay at 0.

Instead split the tweet and iterate over its words:

```
for word in tweet.split():
  if word in positive_words:
    count_positive = count_positive + 1
```

And similarly for the negative words.

EDIT: (contributed in Schmuddi's answer) also note that in order to compute the correct ratio, instead of dividing by `len(tweet)`, which will give you the number of characters in `tweet`, you need to divide by the number of **words** in `tweet`(i.e `len(tweet.split())`).

Answer (score 3):

There are a few issues with your code.

(1) As pointed out in Ivaylo's answer, you need to split the tweet into words. You can do this by `tweet.split()`.

(2) You need to determine the length of the tweet in words, not in characters: `len(tweet)` for the first tweet gives you `16` because there are 16 characters in `this is terrible`, but there are 3 words.

(3) In Python 2.x (but not in Python 3.x), an expression like `i / j` is an integer division for as long as all involved variables are integers, which is the case with your `count_positive` and `count_negative` variables as well as your `len(tweet)`. You have to make sure that this is a float division.

Here's a revision of your code that fixes these issues.

```py
# You can use the following line to make Python 2.7 behave like Python 3.x
# with regard to divisions: if you import 'division' from the __future__ 
# module, divisions that use the '/' operator will be float, and divisions
# that use the '//'  will be integer. 
from __future__ import division 

negative_words = ['bad', 'terrible']
positive_words = ['outstanding', 'good']

tweets = ["this is terrible", "this is very good"]

for tweet in tweets:
    # split the tweet into words:
    words = tweet.split() 

    # use list comprehensions to create lists of positive and negative 
    # words in the current tweet, and use 'len()' to get the counts in 
    # each list:
    count_positive = len([w for w in words if w in positive_words])
    count_negative = len([w for w in words if w in negative_words])

    # divide the counts by the number of words:
    ratio_positive = count_positive / len(words)
    ratio_negative = count_negative / len(words)

    print(ratio_positive)
    print(ratio_negative)
```

**Edit:** Note that an earlier version used the [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class from the `collections` module. This is, in general, a very useful class, but it was overkill in the present case (and didn't quite work yet).

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are using Python 2, because it will perform integer division.
You should use **float ()** function to avoid it:

```
>>> 5 / 2
2
>>> float (5) / 2
2.5
```